# Two reference lists in one doc

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I need to make custom commands for in-text citations that will cause entries to be automatically added to two tables like the one in the image [image: what i need]

Depending on the type of document referenced

I'm trying to do something about it and so far the code below produces something like this. So I can't figure out if it's possible to somehow, based on the command used (`ADcite` vs `RDcite`) or based on the entry in the *bib files (`usera` field), decide which list of references the description should go to. And in general, is it possible to make two lists? Could you please help?

[image: what i have now]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
  >{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}



\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=identifier, fieldtarget=userb]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=revision, fieldtarget=userc]
    }
    % Map entries to the "AD" category if "bibtype" is "AD"
    \map[overwrite]
    {
      \step[fieldsource=usera, match=\regexp{AD}, final]
      %\step[category=AD, final]
    }
    % Map entries to the "RD" category if "bibtype" is "RD"
    \map[overwrite]
    {
      \step[fieldsource=usera, match=\regexp{RD}, final]
      %\step[category=RD, final]
    }
  }
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% AD
\newcommand*{\ADcitenum}[1]{AD#1}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\ADcite}
  {\printfield{userb}\space}
  {\bibhyperref{\mkbibbrackets{AD\thefield{labelnumber}}}}
  {\addcomma\space}
  {}

% Use the custom citation command as the default
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ADcitenum{#1}}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular1}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{| C{\dimexpr0.08\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} |}
     \hline
     \rowcolor{lightgray} % Apply the custom row color to the first row
     \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Identifier} & \textbf{Revision}\\
     \hline
     \endfirsthead
     \hline
     \endhead
     \hline
     \endfoot
     \hline
     \endlastfoot}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{%
     \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}}}
   & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{title}}
   & \plainlang{\printfield{userb}}
   & \plainlang{\printfield{userc}} \\}



\addbibresource{applicable.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RD
\newcommand*{\RDcitenum}[1]{RD#1}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\RDcite}
  {\printfield{userb}\space}
  {\bibhyperref{\mkbibbrackets{RD\thefield{labelnumber}}}}
  {\addcomma\space}
  {}
  
% Use the custom citation command as the default
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\RDcitenum{#1}}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular2}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{| C{\dimexpr0.08\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} |}
     \hline
     \rowcolor{lightgray} % Apply the custom row color to the first row
     \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Identifier} & \textbf{Revision}\\
     \hline
     \endfirsthead
     \hline
     \endhead
     \hline
     \endfoot
     \hline
     \endlastfoot}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{%
     \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}}}
   & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{title}}
   & \plainlang{\printfield{userb}}
   & \plainlang{\printfield{userc}} \\}
   
   

\addbibresource{references.bib}


% No title at the start of the bibliography
\defbibheading{bibliography}[]{}




\begin{document}

\section{Applicable and reference documents}

\subsection{Applicable documents}
\begin{center}
    \printbibtabular[env=bibtabular1]
    \captionof{table}{Applicable documents}
\end{center}

\subsection{Reference documents}
\begin{center}
\printbibtabular[env=bibtabular2]
\captionof{table}{Reference documents}
\end{center}

Test
\\  
\ADcite{doc1}
\\
\RDcite{doc2}
\end{document}
```

applicable.bib file:

```
@misc{doc1,
  usera = {AD},
  title = {Document Title 1},
  identifier = {ID-001},
  revision = {Rev-1},
}
```

references.bib file:

```
@misc{doc2,
  usera = {RD},
  title = {Document Title 2},
  identifier = {ID-002},
  revision = {Rev-2},
}
```

EDIT: keywords used:
So I have applied keywords in the *.bib files, it is like:

```
@misc{doc1,
  keywords = {AD},
  title = {Document Title 1},
  identifier = {ID-001},
  revision = {Rev-1},
}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable} % Required for customizing glossary column widths
\usepackage{hyperref}



\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
  >{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}



\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match={AD}, final] % Filter for AD
      \step[fieldsource=identifier, fieldtarget=userb]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match={RD}, final] % Filter for RD
      \step[fieldsource=identifier, fieldtarget=userb]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=revision, fieldtarget=userc]
    }
  }
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% AD
\newcommand*{\ADcitenum}[1]{AD#1}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\ADcite}
  {\printfield{labelprefix}} % Print the correct labelprefix for AD
  {\bibhyperref{\mkbibbrackets{AD\thefield{labelnumber}}}}
  {\addcomma\space}
  {}

% Use the custom citation command as the default
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ADcitenum{#1}}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular1}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{| C{\dimexpr0.08\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} |}
     \hline
     \rowcolor{lightgray} % Apply the custom row color to the first row
     \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Identifier} & \textbf{Revision}\\
     \hline
     \endfirsthead
     \hline
     \endhead
     \hline
     \endfoot
     \hline
     \endlastfoot}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{%
     \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}}}
   & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{title}}
   & \plainlang{\printfield{userb}}
   & \plainlang{\printfield{userc}} \\}



\addbibresource{applicable.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% RD
\newcommand*{\RDcitenum}[1]{RD#1}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\RDcite}
  {\printfield{labelprefix}} % Print the correct labelprefix for RD
  {\bibhyperref{\mkbibbrackets{RD\thefield{labelnumber}}}}
  {\addcomma\space}
  {}
  
% Use the custom citation command as the default
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\RDcitenum{#1}}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular2}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{| C{\dimexpr0.08\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} | L{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} |}
     \hline
     \rowcolor{lightgray} % Apply the custom row color to the first row
     \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Identifier} & \textbf{Revision}\\
     \hline
     \endfirsthead
     \hline
     \endhead
     \hline
     \endfoot
     \hline
     \endlastfoot}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{%
     \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}}}
   & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{title}}
   & \plainlang{\printfield{userb}}
   & \plainlang{\printfield{userc}} \\}
   
   

\addbibresource{references.bib}


% No title at the start of the bibliography
\defbibheading{bibliography}[]{}




\begin{document}

\section{Applicable and reference documents}

\subsection{Applicable documents}
\begin{center}
    \printbibtabular[env=bibtabular1, keyword=AD] % Filter for AD
    \captionof{table}{Applicable documents}
\end{center}

\subsection{Reference documents}
\begin{center}
\printbibtabular[env=bibtabular2, keyword=RD] % Filter for RD
\captionof{table}{Reference documents}
\end{center}

Test \\
\ADcite{doc1} \\
\RDcite{doc2}

\end{document}
```

It makes it much better now, but "Applicable documents" label prefix is incorrect in the table (RD1 instead of AD1). For now can't find a way to fix it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Things are much easier with `labelprefix`. With that feature `biblatex` automatically adds "RD" or "AD" as required and you don't even need to define two separate `\...cite` commands. You also don't need to define two separate bibliography environments. (In the code from the question the two `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}` would overwrite each other, so that only the second prevailed leaving you always with "RD".)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, defernumbers]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable} % Required for customizing glossary column widths
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
  >{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match={AD}, final] % Filter for AD
      \step[fieldsource=identifier, fieldtarget=userb]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=keywords, match={RD}, final] % Filter for RD
      \step[fieldsource=identifier, fieldtarget=userb]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=revision, fieldtarget=userc]
    }
  }
}


\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{
     | C{\dimexpr0.1\textwidth\relax}
     | L{\dimexpr0.6\textwidth-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
     | L{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth\relax}
     | L{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth\relax} |}
     \hline
     \rowcolor{lightgray} % Apply the custom row color to the first row
     \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Identifier} & \textbf{Revision}\\
     \hline
     \endfirsthead
     \hline
     \endhead
     \hline
     \endfoot
     \hline
     \endlastfoot}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{%
     \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}}}
   & \plainlang{\usebibmacro{title}}
   & \plainlang{\printfield{userb}}
   & \plainlang{\printfield{userc}} \\}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{doc1,
  keywords = {AD},
  title = {Document Title 1},
  identifier = {ID-001},
  revision = {Rev-1},
}
@misc{doc2,
  keywords = {RD},
  title = {Document Title 2},
  identifier = {ID-002},
  revision = {Rev-2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\section{Applicable and reference documents}

\subsection{Applicable documents}
\begin{center}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=AD]
\printbibtabular[env=bibtabular, heading=none, keyword=AD] % Filter for AD
\captionof{table}{Applicable documents}
\end{center}

\subsection{Reference documents}
\begin{center}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=RD]
\printbibtabular[env=bibtabular, heading=none, keyword=RD] % Filter for RD
\captionof{table}{Reference documents}
\end{center}

Test

\cite{doc1} 

\cite{doc2}

\end{document}
```

[image: Two tabular bibliographies. One with AD1 and one with RD1.]

Comment: As always, worth waiting for your answer (before even trying to attempt one)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just one more problem here. Namely, I add `\captionof{}` to tables and they are numbered as 2 and 4 (I would like 1 and 2), as you can see. So the `longtable` in `defbibtabular` increments the table counter, except that I don't display this caption with `longtable`. And I don't do it because I don't know how to do it to have different captions for the two tables: "Applicable document" and "Reference documents". I can only add `\caption{}`, which will appear with the same description for both tables. Could you please help with this?

Comment: @bLAZ There is `\begin{longtable*}...\end{longtable*}`. If that does not help, please ask a new question as the caption doesn't really have anything to do with the issues originally asked about in this question.